# How can I refer to "original" opener window from a chain of opened windows?

Tags: javascript

I have a web app (A).

It opens a new window (B) to do something.

As a result of actions in the new window, I want to do something to the original app, and this can be done by referencing the original window as `window.opener` in the new window.

However, what if the new window (B) opens its OWN new window (C)?

If I refer to `window.opener` in (C), it will be window (B), not (A).

Is there any way to force C's `window.opener` to be "A" - the original window?

I was thinking of running something like `parent = current_window.opener; current_window=parent;` in a loop till `parent` is null.... but that will fail if one of my mid-level windows gets closed in the interim! So I need to force the window.opener to be the correct value right away, when a new window opens.

Comment: Can you access the opener window's variables when it's opened to constantly set `current_window.opener` when the window opens with only one lookback? Something like `original_opener = window.opener.original_opener`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight - let me try

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the window's opener property when you open it:

```
var wnd = window.open(...);
if(window.opener)
{
  wnd.opener = window.opener();
}
```

This is untested though :)

Might need to change the nature of the condition in the if statement. Basically, you want to determine whether the window has a parent, and if it does, give its child window the same parent. In the original opener, window.opener could be undefined, or null. Not sure :)